# Creating two dodged barplots stacked on top of each other for my two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, tidyr

Say that I have a data frame that looks like this...

```
#create dataframe
rG_activity <- c("0.368", "0.468", "0.427", "0.091")
rG_activity_error_intervals <- c("(0.468, 0.268)", "(0.568, 0.368)", "(0.527, 0.327)", "(1.091, -0.909)")
rG_task_persistence <- c("-0.462", "-0.345", "-0.291", "-1.062")
rG_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.562, -0.362)", "(-0.445, -0.245)", "(-0.391, -0.191)", "(-2.091, -0.062)")
rE_activity <- c("-0.162", "-0.245", "-0.129", "-0.462")
rE_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.262, -0.062)", "(-0.345, -0.145)", "(-0.229, -0.029)", "(-0.562, -0.362)")
rE_task_persistence <- c("-0.362", "-0.245", "-0.191", "-0.162")
rE_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.462, -0.262)", "(-0.345, -0.145)", "(-0.291, -0.091)", "(-0.262, -0.062)")
age <- c("30", "24", "18", "12")
df <- data.frame(age, rG_activity, rG_activity_error_intervals, rG_task_persistence, rG_task_persistence_error_intervals, rE_activity, rE_activity_error_intervals, rE_task_persistence, rE_task_persistence_error_intervals)

  age rG_activity rG_activity_error_intervals rG_task_persistence rG_task_persistence_error_intervals rE_activity rE_activity_error_intervals
1  30       0.368              (0.468, 0.268)              -0.462                    (-0.562, -0.362)      -0.162            (-0.262, -0.062)
2  24       0.468              (0.568, 0.368)              -0.345                    (-0.445, -0.245)      -0.245            (-0.345, -0.145)
3  18       0.427              (0.527, 0.327)              -0.291                    (-0.391, -0.191)      -0.129            (-0.229, -0.029)
4  12       0.091             (1.091, -0.909)              -1.062                    (-2.091, -0.062)      -0.462            (-0.562, -0.362)
  rE_task_persistence rE_task_persistence_error_intervals
1              -0.362                    (-0.462, -0.262)
2              -0.245                    (-0.345, -0.145)
3              -0.191                    (-0.291, -0.091)
4              -0.162                    (-0.262, -0.062)
```

The two main variables of interest are "activity" and "task_persistence". For instance, for activity, I have rG_activity and rE_activity for each age (12, 18, 24, 30), same for task_persistence, along with the respective error intervals for each age. I would like to create two dodged bar plots for "activity" and "task_persistence" stacked on top of each other just like my example below (which includes the error intervals and the legend at the bottom). (note: the values on the barplot below do not reflect the values in my sample data above). Would appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question relates more to data cleaning and wrangling than plotting. Creating your barchart is actually the simple part. But here you go:

```
# requires tidyr 1.3.0

library(tidyverse)

df_tidy <- df |>
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, "_value"), !c(age, ends_with("intervals"))) |>
  pivot_longer(-age,
    names_to = c("what", "type", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "^(.*)_(activity|task_persistence)_(value|error_intervals)$"
  ) |>
  separate_wider_regex(error_intervals,
    patterns = c("\\(", lower = ".*?", ",", upper = ".*?", "\\)")
  ) |>
  mutate(across(c(value, lower, upper), as.numeric),
    age = factor(age, levels = sort(unique(as.numeric(age))))
  )

df_tidy$what <- factor(df_tidy$what, levels = c("rG", "rE"))

df_tidy <- df_tidy |>
  mutate(
    ci_upper = pmax(upper, lower),
    ci_lower = pmin(upper, lower),
    y_label = if_else(value > 0, ci_upper, ci_lower) + .1 * if_else(value > 0, 1, -1),
    vjust = if_else(value > 0, 0, 1)
  )

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(age, value, fill = what)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(width = .9), width = .25) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = value,
      y = y_label,
      vjust = vjust
    ),
    position = position_dodge(width = .9)
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ paste("age", .x)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, .3)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Correlation", fill = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. Could you explain how specified the "rE" and "rG" in the legend?

Comment: I see thanks. Could you show how to tweak the code to reverse the color scheme, such that rG is the darker shade of gray, whereas rE is the lighter shade? And how can we make it so the rG column (the new darker gray column) appears before the rE column (opposite of the way we have it now). Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks! @stefan

So, I made two modifications to the code above  so that it could properly order my age data )(I added more ages) because they had lexographical order before, where it was ordered based on the first number. 

I changed mutate() to include age.. mutate(across(c(age, value, lower, upper), as.numeric)). 

And I changed the scale_x_discrete() to scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("age 3", "age 6", "age 9", "age 12", "age 18", "age 24", "age 30", "age 36")).

However, my x-axis labels are obviously now gone. How could I do this while retaining the labels?

Comment: I kept my initial tweak and followed your last suggestion to stick with scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ paste("age", .x)). Graph looks fine, but there aren't any labels. Do you know why?

Comment: I tried that, but it adds labels (10, 20, 30, 40) that aren't present in the data set. I guess there are two problems here: when I made the age variable continuous ((mutate(across(c(age, value, lower, upper), as.numeric))) such that I could properly order the data (so it could display age 6, age 12, age 18, age 24, age 30, age 36 in order), it messed 1) the confidence intervals and 2) caused the labels in the x-axis to disappear. scale_x_continuous(labels = ~ paste("age", .x)) doesn't seem to do it, as it adds ages that aren't there.

Comment: Worked like a charm! :) The only thing left to fix now are the confidence intervals. They are centered around the labels themselves, not centered on their respect bars. Do you know how I can fix this? Thanks again for all of your help. This is how they look right now: https://i.imgur.com/AyjTErI.png

Comment: Last question @stefan ! If I wanted to display the value of the correlation above each bar (specifically above the error bar portion), how would I go about doing this?

Comment: It's a bit fiddly as we first have to compute/set the right positions for the labels and the vertical alignment. But see my edit.

Comment: Hey @stefan, when you get the chance, could you check out my recent thread? It was too much to ask for in these comments, but I am trying to append an additional columns to the bar plot your code.

Comment: Yeah. That is a lengthly list of comments. I think we could clean them up, i.e. delete them. Especially the one concerned with the scale. (: